# How do I make a for loop that would go through a prior method?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, methods

My current code is in two methods. I am trying to get the first position to switch with the second. For example, some on input 6 & 7. I want that to become 7 & 6, but in my case they are predefined, and are more than two single digits.

My first method:

```
static void nameSwitch (int[] array, int pos1, int pos2 ) {

    int temp = array[pos1];       /*As you all may know, this is the switching of 
    array[pos1] = array[pos2];    position 1 and 2.*/
    array[pos2] = temp;

}
```

My Second Method:

```
static void lastToFirstName() {
    int [] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    for(//this is where I am stuck at.)


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString[values]);
 }
```

I want to output to be [21436587109], and the issue with me is getting to implement the method in the other method and getting the loop correct.

Comment: using recursive method perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears to me that you are switching every other term in `values`.

Original input:

```
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

This can be accomplished in a `for` loop structured similar to this which 'jumps' to every other term and performs the switching operation accordingly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
    nameSwitch(values, i, i + 1);
}
```

Final output:

```
values = {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9};
```

**Edit: Adding compare functionality to the `nameSwitch()` method**

You could edit `nameSwitch()` to take into consideration which number is greater; if `pos1` is greater than `pos2`, the switch would be conducted. Otherwise, `pos1` is less than `pos2` and the method would be immediately returned.

```
static void nameSwitch(int[] array, int pos1, int pos2) {

    if (pos1 < pos2) {
        return;
    }

    int temp = array[pos1];
    array[pos1] = array[pos2];
    array[pos2] = temp;

}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. How about if I had an array of: 5, 6, 10, 3, 9, 11 and i want to compare pos1 with pos 2 and if it is greater, i swap, and if it isn't i will not swap.... I will write it up, i think i can get that now, since i got this!

Comment: You can compare that in your `nameSwitch` method

Comment: What do you mean that I can compare it in my nameSwitch method? If anyhting, it would be in a different method that has conditions to comparing pos1 with pos2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question this code will work

```
static void nameSwitch (int[] array, int pos1, int pos2 ) {
    int temp = array[pos1];       /*As you all may know, this is the switching of position 1 and 2.*/
    array[pos1] = array[pos2];    
    array[pos2] = temp;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i+=2) {
        nameSwitch(values, i, i+1);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 for(int i=0;i+1<values.length;i=i+2)
 {
    nameSwitch(values, i, i+1);
  }
```

Yo need to increment i by 2 in each iteration so the next pair of numbers can be swapped with each other. `i+1<values.length` will ensure that if you have only one element remained for last iteration then it is kept as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Switchnumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    lastToFirstName();
}

static void lastToFirstName() {
    int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i = i + 2) {
        int tmp = values[i];
        values[i] = values[i + 1];
        values[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(values[i]);
    }

}
```

}